# What's a better word for "part" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

The new technology divided the world - or at least the part that could pay - in two: those who [blah blah blah] and those who [blah blah blah].

I would use "or at least those who could pay" but I refer to people using the word "those" in the second part of the sentence, so it would seem repetitive. But I don't think "part" is quite right - or is it just me?

Comment: Paying customers.

Comment: Just repeat "the world", and use a demonstrative: _-- or at least that part of the world that could pay --_

Comment: or at least the **segment** that could pay

Comment: I figured out the reason I don't like "part" is because "part of the world" suggests a particular physical region, like Europe. I like "segment" because it's sufficiently abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the context of the sentence. I'm thinking that there are aggressive approaches, like:

> The new technology split the world in two, at least among punters with money.

Or, the technically correct but painful to read approach, like:

> The new technology divided those who could afford it into two groups.

Or, the writer could simply ignore the cost issue, as in:

> The new technology appealed to two different kinds of people.

Personally, I don't think having two incidences of "those" is nearly as annoying as having both an m-dash and a colon in the same sentence. My advice: when "thesaurus" comes to mind, think "rewrite."

Comment: I think I like the idea of simply ignoring the cost issue, since it's alluded to (albeit less directly) later in the text. I'm going with "When the technology hit the market a few decades ago, two groups of people emerged: those who..."

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what's bothering you may be that the world itself cannot pay and is not divided; rather, the people pay and are divided. It's fine to fudge it a bit, but if you aren't happy, try this:

> The new technology divided the **people of the** world - or at least
>   **the people who** could pay - in two: those who [slathered their toast with oil paints] and those who [had better things to do with
>   their time and art supplies].